# Instance of a class won't run an Overridden method

Tags: java, class, methods, lwjgl, game-engine

I have a package and 2 classes:
`AbstractEntity`
`Entity` (which implements `AbstractEntity`)
`Player` (which extends `Entity`)

I have a `public void method called move()`. which is declared in `AbstracEntity`, `@Overridden` in `Entity` as a blank method and `@Overridden` again in `Player` which my actual move method for the player. However, when I call this code in my main loop:

```
for(Entity entity:allEntities){
    entity.move();
    renderer.processEntity(entity);
}
```

The move method is implemented in the Entity class:
     @Override
     public void move(){
     }

And in the player class as:

```
@Override 
public void move(){

    checkInputs();
    rotY += currentTurnSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();
    float distance = currentSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();

    float dx = (float) (distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotY)));
    float dz = (float) (distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotY)));

    upwardsSpeed+= Gravity * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();
    float dy = upwardsSpeed * DisplayManager.getFrameTimeSeconds();

    if(super.getPosition().y<TerrainHeight){
        upwardsSpeed = 0;
        dy = TerrainHeight - super.getPosition().y;
    }

    super.increasePosition(dx, dy, dz);
    super.setRotation(new Vector4f(0f,(float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(-rotY/2))),0f,(float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(-rotY/2))));

    System.out.println("here");


}
```

This will perform the blank `move()` method rather than the overridden one. I'm unsure how too restructure this too correctly instance it?

Comment: Are you sure that the actual object you are invoking the method on is of Player class and not Entity?

Comment: Please include the relevant code of the `Entity` class and the `Player` class (i.e. the implementation of `move()` in both classes).

Comment: Both implementations added, the entity the method is called on is pulled from an array of Entities, but is added as a player class.

Answer (score 0):

Structure should be like:

```
Player extends Entity
Entity extends AbstractEntity
```

And instance that you are referring to should be of `Player` for calling player method.
`Entity entity = new Player();`

Answer (score 0):

I've found my error and its simply a case of the issue being hidden in code folds. The player entity was never added too the list of entities too be processed and rendered and rather was rendered separately. I've now added it too the allEntities array and it functions as intended. Several hours of frustration could have been avoided if I'd just opened my code fold.

Comment: add this in your question in its end as an **EDIT** Section